# adding ios core framework to podfile

Tags: ios, admob, cocoapods, podfile, linker-flags

I added a pod to my Podfile and got compiler errors when building:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CLLocation", referenced from:
     objc-class-ref in MoPubAdapter(GADMAdapterMoPub.o)
  ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I then went to `Build Settings > Target > Debug > Other Linker Files` and manually added `-framework` and `"CoreLocation"`.

[image]

The compiler did not complain anymore. I assume they were forgotten in as prerequisites for the pod.

Now I don't like the fact that I manually changed this value. I might forget to do this if Cocoapods i.e. overwrites this value again. Is there a way for me do add the `CoreLocation` framework to the Podfile so that Cocoapods takes care of including it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**I am afraid there is no way to do that**. Apple does not provide dependency of it's core frameworks on `Cocoapods`. As a test, you can search for any core library on Cocoapods. You won't find that. As a brief test, here is the result if you try to set `pod CoreLocation` in **Podfile**.

[image]

Sadly, fixing this manually is the only workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a dependency in your Podfile to a minimal CocoaPod that only adds a dependency to CoreLocation.  See [here](https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/making-a-cocoapod.html) for creating a podspec and [here](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#pod) for referencing a podspec from a local path.

A better solution would be to update the offending pod's podspec to add CoreLocation as a [framework](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#frameworks).